# SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns error when loading element collections via entity graph

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an invoice entity which amongst other things like billing , shipping address, customer, etc, also saves payments and invoice line items. I'm using named entity graphs to load different associations for each of the custom repository methods I have defined.

The invoice class

```
@Slf4j
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Where(clause = "DELETED = 0")
@Relation(collectionRelation = "invoices")
@Table(indexes = { @Index(name = "place_of_supply_index", columnList = "placeOfSupply", unique = false),
    @Index(name = "invoice_date_index", columnList = "invoiceDate", unique = false),
    @Index(name = "due_date_index", columnList = "dueDate", unique = false),
    @Index(name = "payment_terms_index", columnList = "paymentTerms", unique = false) })
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "invoice_customer_details", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("customer") }),
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "invoice_details", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("customer"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("billedTo"), @NamedAttributeNode("shippedTo") }),
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "invoice_billing_details", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("lineItems"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("payments") }),
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "invoice_all_details", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("customer"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("billedTo"), @NamedAttributeNode("shippedTo"), @NamedAttributeNode("lineItems"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("payments") }), })
public class Invoice extends AuditableEntity implements Identifiable<Long>, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1560474818107754225L;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Cannot save invoice without Invoice Number")
  //@NaturalId
  @Column(unique = true, length = 20, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private String invoiceNumber;

  @JsonIgnore
  private Integer deleted = 0;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Cannot save invoice without Line Items")
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @CollectionTable(name = "invoice_line_items", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id"))
  @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY, content = Include.NON_NULL)
  @OrderBy("serialNumber ASC")
  private Set<LineItem> lineItems;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @CollectionTable(name = "invoice_payments", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id"))
  @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY, content = Include.NON_NULL)
  @OrderBy("paymentDate DESC")
  private Set<Payment> payments;
```

In the repository class I define a method to find all paid invoices by a given customer with the entity graph to load `Payments` and `LineItems`

```
  @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
  @EntityGraph(value = "invoice_billing_details", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
  Page<Invoice> findByPaymentsIsNotNullAndCustomer_Id(Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

this method throws the exception

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:312)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.findByPaymentsIsNotNullAndCustomer_Id(Unknown Source)
```

I can't figure out at how to fix this. Here's the test that fails due to error

```
@Test
  public void testFindAllPaidInvoicesByCustomer() throws Exception {
    //other invoice fields are set in the @Before annotated setup method
    invoice.setDueDate(Date.from(LocalDate.now().minusDays(10).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant()));
    invoice.setPaymentTerms("NET-30");
    invoice
        .setInvoiceDate(Date.from(LocalDate.now().minusDays(40).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant()));
    Set<Payment> payments = new HashSet<>();
    payments.add(getPayment());
    invoice.setPayments(payments);
    invoice.setLineItems(builder.getInvoiceObjectWithLineItems().getLineItems());
    Invoice savedInvoice = invoiceRepository.saveAndFlush(invoice);
    em.clear();
    Page<Invoice> invoices = invoiceRepository.findByPaymentsIsNotNullAndCustomer_Id(savedInvoice.getCustomer().getId(),
        PageRequest.of(0, 10));
    assertThat(invoices).isNotEmpty();
    assertThat((new ArrayList<>(invoices.getContent())).get(0).getId()).isEqualTo(savedInvoice.getId());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was due to `private Integer deleted = 0;`

added column mapping and that solved it.

```
  @JsonIgnore
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @ColumnDefault("0")
  private Integer deleted = 0;
```